# Validate input element text when using unit test in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

## Problem

I was trying to solve a VueJs challenge. This challenge had a set of unit tests to validate the correctness of my code. Some of these tests were around an input text field. I was following the usual way to create a custom input component using `v-model` but the tests that check the input validation logic failed.

When the component is mounted the `v-model` has an initial value of `""` (empty string). The test then sets a value using `setValue` and next checks if the input has the correct value using `customInput.element.value`

```js
const app = mount(App);
const customInput = app.find(".custom-input-field-a");

customInput.setValue("invalid input");
expect(customInput.element.value).toEqual("");
```

After the `setValue` statement, the input element triggers an `input` event, handled by the custom component. This handler validates the input text and then emits an `input` event to update the v-model.

When this happens nothing gets updated because the previous and the next value are equal to `""` (no "reactivity" here), thus the statement `customInput.element.value` returns `"invalid input"`

## Code

This is the custom component:

```
<template>
  <div class="custom-input">
    <label :class="labelClasses" :for="name">{{ label }}</label>
    <input
      :class="`custom-input-${name}`"
      :name="name"
      :maxlength="3"
      type="text"
      :value="value"
      @input="onInput"
      @keypress="onlyLettersFilter"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    placeholder: { type: String, default: "some placeholder" },
    label: String,
    value: String,
  },
  computed: {
    hasValue() {
      return this.value?.length > 0;
    },
    labelClasses() {
      return "custom-input--label " + (this.hasValue ? "active" : "");
    },
  },
  methods: {
    filterValue(input) {
      let value = input.slice(0, 3);
      value = value.toUpperCase().replace(/([^A-Z])+/g, "");
      return value;
    },
    onInput(event) {      
      this.$emit("input", this.filterValue(event.target.value));
    },
    onlyLettersFilter(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 13) return true;
      var key = String.fromCharCode(
        !event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode
      );
      // Accept only letters
      var regex = new RegExp(/[a-zA-Z]+/);
      if (regex.test(key)) {
        return true;
      }
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Here you can see that in any input change, the text is filtered, removing unwanted characters. If all characters are invalid, the result is an empty string.

## Workaround

As a workaround, I set a reference to the input element and updated the content directly without using the VueJs capabilities. All tests passed.

```
<template>
  ...
    <input
      ...
      ref="inputRef"
      ...
    />
  ...
</template>
<script>

export default {
  ...
  methods: {
    ...
    
    onInput(event) {
      const value = this.filterValue(event.target.value);
      // this prevents any invalid character in the input element when the model value doesn't change, when seting the value in unit tests
      this.$refs.inputRef.value = value;
      if (value === this.value) event.preventDefault();
      else {
        this.$emit("input", value);
      }
    },
  }
  ...
}
</script>
```

I know this is an awful solution, but I don't know any better.

Is there a better and cleaner way to do this without using ref and modifying the HTML component directly?